# Show alert message if required fields are not filled in angular8

Tags: angular

I have 2 forms, so on click of save button, I want to show an alert message, if mandatory fields are not filled. So, I have given validation messages and all, it was working fine, but now I need to bring entire section of one form when clicked on add button so here I am getting validation error for second form all time, even though the fields are filled. I am not getting where I am going wrong.

TS:

```
 saveDetails() {
    this.submitted = true;
    let errorMesage = '';
    let errorBasic = this.agentbasicInfoForm.invalid || !this.agentbasicInfoForm.dirty || !this.agentbasicInfoForm.touched;
    let errorW9 = this.agentW9InfoForm.invalid || !this.agentW9InfoForm.dirty || !this.agentW9InfoForm.touched
    if(errorBasic && errorW9) {
      errorMesage = 'Please enter required fields in Basic Info and W9'
    } else if(errorBasic && !errorW9) {
      errorMesage = 'Please enter required fields in Basic Info '
    } else {
      errorMesage = 'Please enter required fields in W9'
    }
    if (this.agentbasicInfoForm.invalid || this.agentW9InfoForm.invalid || this.agentbasicInfoForm.dirty || this.agentbasicInfoForm.touched || this.agentW9InfoForm.dirty || this.agentW9InfoForm.touched) {
          this.notificationService.activate("Validation Message",errorMesage,"Ok",false).then(responseOK => {
      if (responseOK) {

        console.log("worked")
      }
    });
    } else {
      // save or edit continues
    }
  }




 get detailsInfo() { return this.agentbasicInfoForm.controls; }

  get w9Info() { return this.w9InfoDetails.controls; }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gje1oi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your `else` clause. You are catching every other scenario including the form being valid and returning 'Please enter required fields in W9'.

Change this to an else if, and the specify the exact scenario you want to catch (form 1 valid, form 2 invalid).

Comment: here, i need to validate properly for w9form, as it is from a array loop

Answer (score 0):

When you use agentbasicInfoForm.invalid you are not only validating the required fields, you are validating the entire reactive form rules that you difined in your constructor, take a look if you have anothers rules of validation in your reactive form constructor, like minLenght, maxLenght ...

Comment: after max length the values it wont take at all, so i am struck with w9form validation

Comment: You can try
<code>
if(errorBasic && errorW9) {
      errorMesage = 'Please enter required fields in Basic Info and W9'
    } else if(errorBasic && !errorW9) {
      errorMesage = 'Please enter required fields in Basic Info '
    } else if(!errorBasic && errorW9){
      errorMesage = 'Please enter required fields in W9'
    } else {
      errorMesage = 'Else here'
    }

</code>

Comment: Here my problem is with how to handle errors for w9form, as it is an formarray inside fork builder, so even though I enter required fields it throws error and doesn’t allow me to save data

Comment: You can use the disabled at submit button with this.agentbasicInfoForm.invalid || this.agentW9InfoForm.invalid, that way the form will submit only if is valid. and to show the errors from required you can use in each input at the html like agentbasicInfoForm.controls['text1'].errors.required